# Creating newcommands using a loop

Tags: macros, loops

I am currently writing a reader and have to write a lot of sub & superscripts so I have written a function

```
    % Define the electric field vector
    \NewDocumentCommand{\vE}{O{#1} O{#2}}{
        \IfValueTF{#1}{
            \IfValueTF{#2}{
                \ensuremath{\supersubs{\vec{E}}{#1}{#2}}
            }{
                \ensuremath{\supersubs{\vec{E}}{#1}{}}
            }
        }{
            \ensuremath{\vec{E}}
        }
    }
```

However I have a variety of symbols which need of super & subscripts so I was wondering if it is possible to create a loop that generates functions based on this template so I can call it in the documents

```
\vE, \vB[2], \vJ[2][3], ...
```

Without having to write the functions for \vB, and \vJ individually?

Comment: you could do, there are lots of loop macros, but why `\vE`, `\vB`  etc rather than a single macro that takes E or B or J as first argument?

Comment: note you need a lot of `%` at ends of lines here (as presumably you are using this command in text mode

Comment: Thanks for the % info. The idea was to make the source code as legible as possible as I didn't want to have many curly braces to be around. I was also curious whether it would be possible. I also thought it is easier to write \vB[][] then \vec{B}[][]

Comment: `\vec B` works so you are only saving a space, but I would use `_` and `^` rather than `[][]` (using the `e` argument type rather than `o` of `\NewDocumentCommand`

Comment: I understand, however I am still wondering whether something like this is possible, out of curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a command that replaces `E` by `#1` then iterate that over a loop, but I would not do this, I'd just define the command to take E as an argument and use `_` and `^` syntax as shown here with `vv` (`here` and `there` just added to show an arbitrary special handling of the superscript syntax)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\supersubs#1#2#3{#1_{#2}^{#3}}%?

\NewDocumentCommand\defv{m}{%
    \ExpandArgs{c}\NewDocumentCommand{v#1}{O{##1} O{##2}}{%
        \IfValueTF{##1}{%
            \IfValueTF{##2}{%
                \ensuremath{\supersubs{\vec{#1}}{##1}{##2}}%
            }{%
                \ensuremath{\supersubs{\vec{#1}}{##1}{}}%
            }%
        }{%
            \ensuremath{\vec{#1}}%
        }%
      }%
    }

    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \clist_map_function:nN{E,B,J}\defv
    \ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand\vv{me{_^}}{\vec{#1}_{#2here}^{#3there}}
    \begin{document}

    $\vJ[1][2]$

    \bigskip
    
    $\vv J_{1}^{2}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

What we can do in OpTeX:

```
\fornum`A..`Z\do{\sdef{v\Uchar#1}{\vec{\Uchar#1}\vecparams}}
\def\vecparams{\isnextchar[{\vecparamsub}{}}
\def\vecparamsub[#1]{_{#1}\isnextchar[{\vecparamsup}{}}
\def\vecparamsup[#1]{^{#1}}

$\vA, \vB[1], \vC[1][2], \vZ$

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd not try doing a batch define, because each letter with the arrow requires moving the superscript by a different amount so it doesn't clash with the arrow.

The usage of `\ensuremath` would just complicate things and hide the mathematical nature of the commands. Don't use it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\genericvector}{mmoo}{%
  \vec{#1}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{^{\mkern#2mu#3}}%
  \IfValueT{#4}{_{#4}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\vA}{}{\genericvector{A}{1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\vE}{}{\genericvector{E}{0}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\vI}{}{\genericvector{I}{3}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\vj}{}{\genericvector{\jmath}{4}}

\begin{document}

$\vA+\vA[2]+\vA[2][3]$

$\vE+\vE[2]+\vE[2][3]$

$\vI+\vI[2]+\vI[2][3]$

$\vj+\vj[2]+\vj[2][3]$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for comparison, here's the output if the adjustment is zero for every case. You should agree it's not acceptable.

[image]

A different input syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\genericvector}{mme{^_}}{%
  \vec{#1}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{^{\mkern#2mu#3}}%
  \IfValueT{#4}{_{#4}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\vA}{}{\genericvector{A}{1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\vE}{}{\genericvector{E}{0}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\vI}{}{\genericvector{I}{3}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\vj}{}{\genericvector{\jmath}{4}}

\begin{document}

$\vA+\vA^2+\vA^2_3$

$\vE+\vE^2+\vE^2_3$

$\vI+\vI^2+\vI^2_3$

$\vj+\vj^2+\vj^2_3$

\end{document}
```

This avoids being puzzled which argument is which. The output would be the same as in the first picture. If you can, switch.

Comment: input would look so much nicer using `e` rather than `oo`  and would allow subscrcipt only

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Added as suggested, although I fear that the OP already has many occurrences of the first syntax.

Comment: meanwhile you were robbed but the profits went to a worthy cause.